# SVG chart - how can i adjust the height of the svg so that all the labels automatically fit inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have x amount of dates which i want to show on this graph, therefore to avoid overlapping labels i added a height increment for each label, however the incremented value pushes the label off the chart

http://jsfiddle.net/pjnyumsv/2

```
//Line 42 in the fiddle
this.outerHeight = 100;

//if i change this it just pushes the line down without adjusting the labels
```

[image]
i cant figure out how to get the last 2 labels to appear, ideally i would want the line chart to get pushed down, or better yet if there was a way of alternating the height of each label so it goes above and below the line.

Comment: Instead of declaring a `width` and a `height` you may declare a `viewBox` attribute:`.attr("viewBox", `0 -50 ${this.outerWidth} ${this.outerHeight + 100}` )` Please observe that the y component of the viewBox is -50 while the height component is `this.outerHeight` + twice as much i.e 100

Comment: @enxaneta can you elaborate as i dont fully understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code at line 51 you have this:

```js
this.svg = $(svg("svg"))
            .attr("width", this.outerWidth)
            .attr("class", "delete-svg2")
            .attr("height", this.outerHeight)
            .attr("backgroundColor", "#ffffff !important")
            .appendTo(this.container);
    };
```

Instead of declaring a `width` and a `height` you may declare a [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute like so:
`.attr("viewBox", 0 -50 ${this.outerWidth} ${this.outerHeight + 100}` )`

The value of the `viewBox` attribute is a list of four numbers x, y, width and height. By declaring a negative `y` you'll add some space above the present viewBox and you'll be able to see the labels. In this case you'll need to increase the height component as well.

Please observe that the y component of the `viewBox` is -50 while the height component is `this.outerHeight` + twice as much i.e 100.

In your code replace the above with:

```js
this.svg = $(svg("svg"))

      .attr("viewBox", `0 -50 ${this.outerWidth} ${this.outerHeight + 100}` )
            .attr("class", "delete-svg2")

            .attr("backgroundColor", "#ffffff !important")
            .appendTo(this.container);
    };
```